# Contending with Smartart cropping bug in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, crop

I recently discovered and started using the Smartart tool in Microsoft Word 2007.  It's a great tool but there seems to be a bug.  All of the smartart items I have created in my document are cropped along the bottom edge, some more so than others.  I, of course, have not intentionally cropped these items.  And according to Microsoft's online help, the only way to crop Smartart is to convert it to clip art, then use Word's cropping tools on the clip art, which is what makes me believe this is a bug.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this bug. It seems to have something to do with the margins of the page. When I make the SmartArt a quarter inch smaller than the available space there is no cropping.